# Update field formatting based on regex pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

df have:

```
id  type
0   [a]+[b]-[c]
1   [b]-[c]
2   [a]*[d]
```

df want:

```
id  type
0   x['a']+x['b']-x['c']
1   x['b']-x['c']
2   x['a']*x['d']
```

For each row I need to add quotes around the items inside the square brackets and also prefix each open square bracket with x

Comment: Whats is your question, how to write the regex or how to apply it to the df column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use regex when there is a simpler approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [0, 1, 2],
    "type": ["[a]+[b]-[c]", "[b]-[c]", "[a]*[d]"]
})

df["type"] = df["type"].str.translate(str.maketrans({"[": "x[\'", "]": "\']"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

for i in df.index:
    df.at[i, 'type'] = re.sub('\[([^\]]*)\]', 'x[\'\g<1>\']', df.at[i, 'type'])
```

Docs for [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).
We capture every paranthesis and it's contents with `'\[([^\]]*)\]'`, and replace it with `x['(contents of the paranthesis)']`. As simple as that :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using a list comprehension :

```
import re

df['type'] = [ ''.join("x{}".format(re.sub(r'([a-z]+)', r"'\1'", x)) 
                                       if x not in ['-', '+', '*'] 
                                       else x for x in re.split("(\+|-|\*)", s)) 
                                  for s in df['type']]
```